# Concatination table in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to write an SQL query that fetches something like this :

| a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | x | 3 |
| 2 | y | 4 |
| 3 | x | 7 |
| 4 | y | 9 |

transforms into the following form:[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQY9O.png)

Here's my coding attempt:

```
SELECT CONCAT (a) AS a , CONCAT (b, -c) as m  FROM viborka
```

and the corresponding output I'm getting:

| a | m |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | x-3 |
| 2 | y-4 |
| 3 | x-7 |
| 4 | y-9 |

I can't merge expressions with X into string 1 and expressions with Y into string 2.

How can I do it?

Comment: What is the logic ? Why  3 and 4 are excluded ?

Comment: Can you define "*merge expressions*"? Why do you want rows with null values in the "*a*" field?

Comment: @ErgestBasha Because need merge data by key B into one cell of the column with the transfer of each entry to a new line. All row expressions with X (there are: x-3 and x-7) merge to 1 row. All row expressions with Y (there are: y-4 and y-9) merge to 2 row.

Comment: @lemon I don't want rows with null values in the "a" field. It's my fail. I want all expressions with X to be under number 1 and expressions with Y to be under number 2.

Comment: Please don't add images in your post. Describe what you're trying to do in words if the expected output is not sufficient.

Comment: I trying write all expressions with X in the formula in line 1, all expressions with Y in the formula in line 2

Comment: If you need to store data in that way, you should rather use an excel datasheet instead of a DBMS table. Using empty strings in place of NULL values is a sql code smell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
select
  case when row_number() over(partition by b order by c) = 1 then a end as a,
  concat(b, '-', c) as m
from t
order by b, c
```

Result:

```
 a     m   
 ----- --- 
 1     x-3 
 null  x-7 
 2     y-4 
 null  y-9
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/TI53X3xm).

Comment: I'm so sorry. The table of the required result was not inserted correctly. For correctly I inserted a picture (link: 1). There should not be null values.

Comment: If you want to show blanks instead of nulls just replace `then a end` by `then a else '' end` at the end of the second line.